# How to convert a string to a mongodb ObjectId?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am successfully able to insert the following in mongo db as a string. But I want it to be inserted as an objectId.

```
parentId": "5ced2388dbbbe124d8671067"
```

This is the parentId in string format.

**How can I convert it to objectId format?**

Comment: do you use nodejs?

Comment: yes node js and mongoclient

Answer (score 5):

**Mongodb 4.0** has introduced **$toObjectId** aggregation to convert string value to an ObjectId. here's an example

```
db.getCollection('foo_collection').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "bar" :  { "$toObjectId": "$bar_id" }
  }},
  { "$out": "new_foo_collection" }
])
```

Here's the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/)

Answer (score 4):

you must use `mongoose` like that

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ced2388dbbbe124d8671067');
```

Comment: Spent an hour bashing my head because I was using 
` import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **mongoose**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let yourId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ced2388dbbbe124d8671067');
```

It will return type `ObjectId` variable .

Comment: I tried it but its show this error ReferenceError: Schema is not defined.Schema  means

Answer (score 1):

in case of typescript:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"; // will work
import * as mongoose from "mongoose"; // won't work
```

then

```
const objectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID
parentId =  "5ced2388dbbbe124d8671067"
let data = new ObjectId(parentId)
console.log(typeof(data))
console.log(typeof(parentId))
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by writing two lines of code to save it as a object id

```
let ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
parentID = ObjectId("5ced2388dbbbe124d8671067")
```